# JAVA - Send class over GCM in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

let's say I have a class called "MyClass". I need to send it from my server to an Android phone over GCM. Now, I am doing this by sending its all fields seperately and constructing MyClass again on the phone. Is there any way to send an object directly over GCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending all the fields separately, you can encode them to your favorite serialized format (XML, JSON, etc...) and pass the String representation of the object in a single field. Then your app would need to have a method to deserialize the object from that field.

Answer (score 0):

Did not get you clearly. But if you mean you just need to send set of fields through GCM create a JSONObject and send it. As far as I know you need to encode the class to JSONObject and decode the Object to the class object again.